# UnusedPrivateMethod - false positive on nested-class builders

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've written a nested-class builder for a complex class and I'm now getting a false positive (*Unused "private" methods should be removed*) on the private method "setEmail", but it's used in the inner class.

```
public class Email extends AbstractDatabaseEntity<Long> {

    private String email;

    protected Email() {
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    private void setEmail(final String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public static final class Builder extends AbstractEntityBuilder<Email> {

        private Builder(Email entity, EntityState state) {
            super(entity, state);
        }

        public static Builder create() {
            return new Builder(new Email(), EntityState.NEW);
        }

        public static Builder from(Email entity) {
            return new Builder(entity, EntityState.BUILT);
        }

        public Builder email(String email) {
            entity.setEmail(email);
            return this;
        }
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractEntityBuilder<T extends Object> {

    protected final EntityState state;
    protected T entity;
    ...

}
```

**SonarQube version: 5.6.3**

**SonarJava 4.4.0.8066**

Thanks!

Comment: Can you precise what is the version of the sonarJava analyzer you are using  (ie that is installed on your sonarqube instance) ?

Comment: Version 4.4.0.8066 installed.

Comment: Have you tried making the method package-protected?

Comment: Using 'protected' fixed the issue. Anyway, we would like to keep working with 'private' modifiers in this specific scenario. We have just realized that in the older version it worked as expected (Sonar 4.5.2 - Java 3.1 - Findbugs 3.3). Isn't it maybe a regression? Anyway, do you know if there is any workaround we can use? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem looks to be already fixed at **SonarJava 4.10.0.10260** in **SonarQube 5.6.3**. After some investigation I realized the fix most likely came from the issue [SONARJAVA-2204](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2204). You should update the plugin version, restart your Sonar instance and analyse your project again to see that the issues are gone now. Just the really problematic code should remain highlighted from now on.

Comment: Issue fixed in this version! Thanks!